# Enhancing/manipulating react children props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was hoping to abstract away the binding of event listeners on children components. Or allow a component to alter props of children.

I'm wanting to express the components in JSX like

```
<DocumentScreen name="Type">
  <DocumentInput value="L" name="(=learner)" icon="lerners.svg" />
  <DocumentInput value="P" name="(=probationary)" icon="probationary.svg" />
  <DocumentInput value="Full" icon="full.svg" />
</DocumentScreen>
```

Which is an enhanced radio or checkbox grouping.

Now I want to enhance the inputs to automagically notify the parent component of changes to store state.

I was hoping this would be possible

`{React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).map((Child => (<Child onClick={() => console.log("yea!")} />)))}`

Or more simply

`{this.props.children.map((Child => (<Child onClick={() => console.log("yea!")} />)))}`

But I get a typescript error

`JSX element type 'Child' does not have any construct or call signatures`

Using

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"typescript": "^3.5.2"
```

**Is this possible or is there another way to achieve this?**

Comment: I used children as array, but I put the components in "[" and "]"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cloneElement`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

```
render() {
        return (
          <div>
          {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                onClick : () => console.log("yea!")
            })   
         })}
         </div>
       ) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you that pointed in me in the right direction. I was missing `onClick` as a prop in the child component. Once I added `onClick: (value: string) => void` and cast child to any it worked.